# maven and red5 dependencies

Tags: java, maven-3, red5

I have a big red5 java project that I'm trying to divide to modules.

I decided to use maven for this task,

created one big maven web project and inside several maven projects (not web) and I added the desired classes in each one of them.

I have red5 installed in a specific location.

it's `lib` directory contains relevant libraries that I need in order to compile my project properly.

I want to add a dependency in main project's pom.xml to add all the jars in red5 location/lib diectory but only for compile time.

which means that i don't need them to be packaged in the jar because they will be available
in the red5 environment that they're gonna be executed in.

how can I configure such a thing?

thanks!

Kfir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing would be to deploy those dependencies in your repository manager and use them as usual dependencies in your Maven build. In you particular case you should define them with the scope provided cause you described they will be used only for compile but will be provided by the environment.

Comment: if I configure the scope as system, i can specify the location of the library using <systemPath>. how can I specify the location of the library using 'provided' scope ?

Comment: oh.. to use provided i need to actually deploy them in my repository. i'm actually talking about a single red5.jar. i prefer to call it as a system jar and specify it's location with system scope instead of deploying it and using provided scope. but thanks for the info. gonna accept this answer, it provides all the relevant information for my question.

Comment: @ufk you can use red5.jar file as internal repository and configure the remaining dependencies with maven repo.